# How do you handle missing data in neural nets for LSTM or CONV1D?

Tags: neural-networks, missing-data, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a device that outputs signals from 26 channels. I have 4 sessions of data that gave out signals from 26 channels and on the 6th session, I lost 5 channels.
I have trained my model with 1-5 sessions of data with 13335x55x26(13335 samples of 55 time-series datax26 channels).
I wanted to test my data with the 5th session which lost 6 channels so my data changed its shape to 3333x55x20. What I did was zero append 6 channels to increase the number of channels from 20 to 26 but my prediction accuracy was 37%.

Any workaround for such a scenario? Like telling the model to avoid zero's?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the model doesn't work well with the missing data coded as zeros is that the model doesn't "know" that a long sequence of zeros means "missing," nor does it "know" to treat missing signal specially. The network just "thinks" zero means zero, so it's operating as if all the zeroes were an ordinary signal.

You can't model data that you don't have. [imputation](/questions/tagged/imputation) is one method to fill in missing data. Basically, you might be able to predict the missing 5 channels by using the signal from the remaining 21.